# Can hardlinks be overwritten without using a temporary file?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, inode

I have a hardlink the must always exist on the filesystem. What inode the hardlink points is not constant. I want to update the hardlink without adding a temporary entry to the directory.

(Creating a file without a directory entry can be done using `open(2)` with the temp flag.)

The issue I'm facing is with replacing/updating the hardlink. From the documentation on the relevant system calls, It seems that I have only two options, and neither avoids a temporary file:

1. Using `renameat`, it is possible to insure that the hardlink always exists. However, it must consume a hardlink and hence necessitating a temporary files (not to mention its inability to dereference symbolic links).
2. using `linkat`, it is possible to produce a hardlink without sacrificing another file. but it cannot overwrite existing files; requiring the deletion of the original hard link.

Is it at all possible to create a link to an inode that replaces an older link with the same name?

Comment: What do you want to change, just the *name* of the link, or the actual *contents* of the (inode->)file where it links to?

Comment: I have different inode that I want the file (directory entry) to point to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have another file to which to switch the link. However
`rename`, `renameat` do not need the inode be linked in the same directory; they just require the inode to exist on the same filesystem, or **more specifically on the same mount point**; otherwise Linux `rename` fails with `EXDEV`:

> `EXDEV`
>   `oldpath`  and `newpath` are not on the same mounted filesystem.  (Linux permits a filesystem to be mounted at multiple points, but rename() does not work across different
>                 mount points, even if the same filesystem is mounted on both.)

---

Since Linux 3.11 there is a way to make a *new* file without linking it to the filesystem: [open(2) has a new flag `O_TMPFILE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> `O_TMPFILE` (since Linux 3.11)
>
> Create an unnamed temporary file.  The pathname argument
>         specifies a directory; an unnamed inode will be created in
>         that directory's filesystem.  Anything written to the
>         resulting file will be lost when the last file descriptor is
>         closed, unless the file is given a name.
>
> `O_TMPFILE` must be specified with one of `O_RDWR` or `O_WRONLY`
>         and, optionally, `O_EXCL`.  If `O_EXCL` is not specified, then
>         `linkat`(2) can be used to link the temporary file into the
>         filesystem, making it permanent, using code like the
>         following:
>
> ```
>       char path[PATH_MAX];
>       fd = open("/path/to/dir", O_TMPFILE | O_RDWR,
>                               S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
>       /* File I/O on 'fd'... */
>       snprintf(path, PATH_MAX,  "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
>       linkat(AT_FDCWD, path, AT_FDCWD, "/path/for/file",
>                               AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW);
> ```
>
> In this case, the `open()` mode argument determines the file
>         permission mode, as with `O_CREAT`.

The manual tells that one of the 2 common use cases for `O_TMPFILE` is

> Creating a file that is initially invisible, which is then
>             populated with data and adjusted to have appropriate
>             filesystem attributes (chown(2), chmod(2), fsetxattr(2),
>             etc.)  before being atomically linked into the filesystem
>             in a fully formed state (using linkat(2) as described
>             above).

There are many downsides for this, apart from it being quite new: the file system must also support `O_TMPFILE`; ext[234] do support it, and so does XFS in 3.15; btrfs in 3.16; furthermore it might still not be a match for your case, as the `linkat` requires the `AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW` which is not available for `renameat`; if the target name already exists, `linkat  does *not* replace the the target.

Comment: It's a shame that a temporary file must be created. There seems to be non official interest in adding `AT_REPLACE` which would solve this problem[1] but other than that, a temp file is the only way to go. [1]:http://lwn.net/Articles/559969/